# Why do I get differing results subtracting two dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to subtract the losers score from the winner.  Sometimes the result is a positive (good).  Sometimes negative (bad).  I want a consistent positive.  Two examples below:

The good result:  houston - boston = +65 program works

```
some_games = [ {'manchester': 18, 'boston': 3},
 {'cambridge': 17, 'houston': 25}, 
 {'berlin': 10, 'manchester': 10},
 {'houston': 100, 'boston': 35}
 ]

some_ratings = {'manchester': 120,
                'boston': 90, 
                'cambridge': 110, 
                'houston': 90, 
                'berlin': 100}
 
margin_rates = {0: 0, 8: 10, 15: 16, 30: 28}

constant = 8

for game in some_games:
    winner = max(game)
    loser = min(game)
    teams = winner, loser
    print(teams)

    ratings_difference = some_ratings[winner] - some_ratings[loser]
    print(ratings_difference)

    winning_margin = game[winner] - game[loser]
    print(winning_margin)

    if winning_margin >= 64:
        rating_increment = 318.56
    else:
        rating_increment = (margin_rates[winning_margin])

    print(rating_increment)
    some_ratings[winner] = some_ratings[winner] + (rating_increment - ratings_difference)/constant
    some_ratings[loser] = some_ratings[loser] - (rating_increment + ratings_difference)/constant

print(some_ratings)
```

The bad result: houston - manchester = -8. Program crashes

```
some_games = [ {'manchester': 18, 'boston': 3},
 {'cambridge': 17, 'houston': 25}, 
 {'berlin': 10, 'manchester': 10},
 {'houston': 8, 'manchester': 0} ]

some_ratings = {'manchester': 120,
                'boston': 90, 
                'cambridge': 110, 
                'houston': 90, 
                'berlin': 100}
 
margin_rates = {0: 0, 8: 10, 15: 16, 30: 28}

constant = 8

for game in some_games:
    winner = max(game)
    loser = min(game)
    teams = winner, loser
    
    ratings_difference = some_ratings[winner] - some_ratings[loser]

    winning_margin = game[winner] - game[loser]
    

    if winning_margin >= 64:
        rating_increment = 318.56   
    else:
        rating_increment = (margin_rates[winning_margin])
        
    some_ratings[winner] = some_ratings[winner] + (rating_increment - ratings_difference)/constant
    some_ratings[loser] = some_ratings[loser] - (rating_increment + ratings_difference)/constant

print(some_ratings)
```

Error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\a_r_ratings\Experiments\rating_incr_calc_plus65.py", line 29, in 
rating_increment = (margin_rates[winning_margin])
KeyError: -8

Comment: How exactly are you trying to determine the `winner` and `loser` using `max`, especially when there are ties?

Comment: you do realize that the winner and loser are being calculated by a string not by integer values. you're passing dictionary keys to max and min to determine winner or looser.

Comment: Navneec I haven't got around to thinking about ties yet

Vishal the code has been producing what I want: The name of the winning and losing teams and the difference what they have each scored.  ie most of the time it has answered the questions: if john has 8 apples and jack 6. Who has more apples: john correct.  How many more apples does john have. I was consistently getting (plus)2 until the -2 popped up above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `winner = max(game)`

`loser = min(game)`

You are getting the min and max of the keys.
To get the key of the max and min values, try using:

`winner = max(game, key=game.get)`

`loser = min(game, key=game.get)`

Comment: Erick I do not understand why I would want to.  As set out above, I just need the program to tell me how many more apples john has